# C++: Map of abstract pointers appears to be slicing to abstract class

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I was in the midst of memory management in a C++ when I ran head-on into this problem. When I try to delete abstract pointers from a map at the end of the Solver class, a seg-fault will sometimes occur. This only happens for a few values, though, not all.

I used dbx as exhaustively as I know how, and I found that the pointers were valid, but on the deletes that failed they were pointing to what seems to be a vanilla Configuration, rather than something like the example PegConfiguration below. Calls to all virtual methods such as toString() and even isGoal() fail on those pointers, but non-virtual methods like stepsToString() work fine.

[This guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526275/c-calling-derived-function-from-abstract-base-pointer) problem looks similar, but I can't understand the solutions there. He said he solved it, but didn't really say how.

Solver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "Solver.h"
#include "Configuration.h"

using namespace std;

deque<Configuration*> Solver::solve(Configuration* initial)
{

paths.insert(pair<string,Configuration*>(initial->toString(), initial));

configs.push_back(initial);



//Continue while there are still configurations
//and the current configuration is not the goal
while(!configs.empty() &&
      !configs.front()->isGoal())
{
    Configuration* cfg = configs.front();
    configs.pop_front();


    //if the configuration cannot lead to the solution, throw away
    if(!(cfg->isFailure()))
    {

        vector<Configuration*> newConfigs = (cfg->getNeighbors());
        for(int i = 0; i < newConfigs.size(); i++)
        {
            Configuration* newConfig = newConfigs[i];

            //if it is a new config, not in the map
            if(paths.insert(pair<string, Configuration*>(newConfig->toString(),     cfg)).second)
            {
               configs.push_back(newConfig);
            }
            else
            {
                //delete newConfig;
            }
        }
    }

}//end while



//if there was a solution, work it out
//if there is none, return empty vector
if(!configs.empty())
{
    // put  goal configuration value in solutions stack
    // find previous configuration in map
    // put that configuration value in stack
    // continue until previous configuration == current configuration
    // in other words, reached initial configuration
    //send solution stack back to main
    //which will handle printing it out

    //remove pointers from previous containers,
    //so their deletion doesn't screw things up

    Configuration* cfg = configs.front();
    configs.pop_front();

    string key;
    do
    {
        solutions.push_front(cfg);
        key = cfg->toString();
        cfg = paths[key];
        paths[key] = NULL;
    } while(!(cfg->toString() == key));
}




//clean up
for(map<string, Configuration*>::iterator iter = paths.begin();
    iter != paths.end();
    iter++)
{
    delete iter->second;   //problem occurs HERE
}

for(int i = 0; i < configs.size(); ++i)
{
    delete configs[i];
}

paths.clear();
configs.clear();

return solutions;
}//end solve
```

Configuration.h

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_H
#define CONFIGURATION_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Configuration
{

public:


    /**
     * Destructor initialized as virtual so that it can be overridden by
     * subclasses.
     */
    virtual ~Configuration() {}



    /**
     * Does this configuration match the target value?
     *
     * @return true if match, false elsewise
     */
    virtual bool isGoal() const;


    /**
     * Can this configuration ever be solved?
     *
     * @returns true if impossible to solve, false elsewise
     */
    virtual bool isFailure() const = 0;


    /**
     * Basic string representation of configuration. Differs for each class.
     *
     * @returns string representation of configuration
     */
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;



    /**
     * Comparation operator for map-sorting. Compares configuration values.
     *
     * @returns true if value is greater than other's value, false elsewise
     */
    bool operator<(const Configuration& other ) const;



    /**
     * Return all of this config's neighbors (difference of only a single step).
     *
     & @returns  vector of new configurations
     */
    virtual std::vector<Configuration*> getNeighbors() = 0;


    /**
     *
     * @returns string representation of valid steps.
     */
    std::string stepsToString();



protected:


    // contains the steps that are possible for this configuration to reach
    // another valid configuration
    static std::vector<int> steps;


    //the target configuration value
    static int _goal;


    //the current value of this configuration
    int _value;

};//end Configuration

#endif
```

Configuration.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Configuration.h"

using namespace std;


int Configuration::_goal = 1234;
vector<int> Configuration::steps;




//
// Name: isGoal()
//
bool Configuration::isGoal() const
{
    return (_value == Configuration::_goal);
}




//
// Name: operator<
//
bool Configuration::operator<(const Configuration& other) const
{
    bool answer = false;

    if(_value < other._value) { answer = true; }

    return answer;
}



//
// Name: stepsToString
//
string Configuration::stepsToString()
{

    stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < Configuration::steps.size(); i++)
    {
        ss << Configuration::steps[i] << "  ";
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

PegConfiguration.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "PegConfiguration.h"

using namespace std;

vector<char> PegConfiguration::goal;


/**
 * Value constructor.
 *
 * @param value  board value of new Configuration
 */
PegConfiguration::PegConfiguration(vector<char> val, int empty):
    value(val),
    emptyIndex(empty) {}



/**
 * Copy constructor.
 *
 * @param configuration to copy
 */
PegConfiguration::PegConfiguration(const PegConfiguration::PegConfiguration& copy):
    value(copy.value),
    emptyIndex(copy.emptyIndex) {}



/**
 * Constructor for initial puzzle configuration. Given the initial number
 * of pegs on one side of the board, it constructs the initial and goal
 * value.
 *
 * @param numPegs  number of pegs on one side of board
 */
PegConfiguration::PegConfiguration(int numPegs):
    value(2 * numPegs + 1, '.'),
    emptyIndex(numPegs)
{
    goal = vector<char>(2 * numPegs + 1, '.');

    fill(value.begin(), value.begin() + numPegs, 'R');
    fill(value.rbegin(), value.rbegin() + numPegs, 'B');

    fill(goal.begin(), goal.begin() + numPegs, 'B');
    fill(goal.rbegin(), goal.rbegin() + numPegs, 'R');
}



/**
 *  Goal configuration is an exact mirror of the initial board.
 *
 * @returns true if this is the goal configuration.
 */
bool PegConfiguration::isGoal() const
{
    return (value == goal);
}



/**
 * Is this puzzle impossible to solve? Nope.
 *
 * @returns false always.
 */
bool PegConfiguration::isFailure() const
{
    return false;
}


/**
 * Basic string representation of configuration value.
 *
 * @returns string representation of configuration value
 */
std::string PegConfiguration::toString() const
{
    stringstream ss;

    for(int i = 0; i < value.size(); ++i)
    {
        ss << value[i] << " ";
    }

    return ss.str();
}//end toString


/**
 * The empty space can either move one space right or left, or jump
 * two spaces right or left, in both cases swapping with the peg in that
 * location. The only restriction is where the peg is -- if it's too far
 * to the left, it can't jump left, for example.
 *
 * @returns vector of neighbor configuration pointers
 */
std::vector<Configuration*> PegConfiguration::getNeighbors()
{
    vector<Configuration*> neighbors;


    //jump one to the left
    if((emptyIndex - 1) >= 0)
    {
        vector<char> newValue(value);
        (newValue[emptyIndex], newValue[emptyIndex - 1]);

        neighbors.push_back(new PegConfiguration(newValue, emptyIndex - 1));
    }


    //jump two to the left
    if((emptyIndex - 2) >= 0)
    {
        vector<char> newValue(value);
        swap(newValue[emptyIndex], newValue[emptyIndex - 2]);

        neighbors.push_back(new PegConfiguration(newValue, emptyIndex - 2));
    }


    //jump one to the right
    if((emptyIndex + 1) < value.size())
    {
        vector<char> newValue(value);
        swap(newValue[emptyIndex], newValue[emptyIndex + 1]);

        neighbors.push_back(new PegConfiguration(newValue, emptyIndex + 1));
    }


    //jump two to the right
    if((emptyIndex + 2) < value.size())
    {
        vector<char> newValue(value);
        swap(newValue[emptyIndex], newValue[emptyIndex + 2]);

        neighbors.push_back(new PegConfiguration(newValue, emptyIndex + 2));
    }

    return neighbors;

}//end getNeighbors
```

Comment: A much-appreciated courtesy is reducing your code to just the minimum necessary to reproduce the error... most of the time you'll find the bug while you're doing that, and you're less likely to miss things yourself (e.g. PegConfiguration.h).

Comment: Sorry. I admit PegConfiguration is extra, but I really don't know what's causing the bug, just where it occurs. There's a lot of little pit-traps like this in C++ that I just don't know about.

Comment: One thing that confuses me is why aren't all of your methods in Configuration? Since it is an abstract class, it doesn't make sense to declare some methods as virtual, but not others.

Comment: There are several other Configuration subclasses that can go through Solver. A lot of them reuse the functionality in the non-virtual methods in Configuration.

Comment: I'm contemplating opening a couple more accounts on StackOverflow to upvote @Tony's comment a couple more times. I can't over-emphasize how important it is to know how to ask a question. It's hard, I know, tell me about it, but you can't dump on us (almost) all your code and expect us to read through it in search for subtleties. Do your homework, carefully go through your code again, eliminate anything that would surely just waste our time and drive our patience away. It's for your own benefit. And sometimes you gain much more than you expected in this process -- find the answer yourself even.

Comment: I see requests for more code on SO a lot. I'm sorry about erring on the other side. The trouble is I really don't know what's going on -- it could be something to do with the map, or something to do with Configuration (I just learned about needing a virtual destructor for a base class). If I don't have an answer by tomorrow, I'll try to cut it down, but I've already spent the last six hours debugging this and getting no closer to a solution. I'm done with homework for tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is clear. This line:

```
if(paths.insert(pair<string, Configuration*>(newConfig->toString(),     cfg)).second)
```

In your solver function will result in the insertion of the `cfg` pointer several times into the `paths` map. At the end, you traverse that map and `delete` all its elements. If the same pointer is present more than once in the map, it will be deleted more than once, and thus, you will get a crash.

This also explains what you are observing with the debugger. If a class has already been deleted, its vtable gets "rewinded" to the basic class version of the vtable, i.e. a "vanilla" configuration as you pointed out.

The line given above looks suspicious to me, are you sure it is correct?

If it is correct, and `cfg` should indeed appear several times in the `paths` map, then I suggest you use `boost::shared_ptr` or equivalently `std::tr1::shared_ptr` to implement the proper reference counting and automatic deletion that you need.

Comment: This does it! I really do feel stupid now, but it's been eight weeks since I programmed that algorithm -- I would never have found this without help. I always thought a double delete would leave a pointer pointing to random garbage values, not a recognizable parent class. The map is supposed to hold several duplicate values -- it's a traceback map. The string value of a configuration points to the configuration it first came from.

Comment: If you are doing some graph algorithms, as this looks like a path-planning algorithm, I suggest you take a look at Boost Graph Library. There is for instance an A* algorithm in there.